# Namedtuple '_source' method is deactivated after being referenced using 'exec'

Tags: python, python-3.x

`_source` is one method of `namedtuple`, specified in [8.3. collections — Container datatypes — Python 3.6.4rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

An example of its usage:

```
In [90]: Book = namedtuple('Book', 'name, author')
In [91]: Book._source
Out[91]: "from builtins import property as _property, tuple as _tuple\nfrom operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter\nfrom collections import OrderedDict\n\nclass Book(tuple):\n    'Book(name, author)'\n\n    __slots__ = ()\n\n    _fields = ('name', 'author')\n\n    def __new__(_cls, name, author):\n        'Create new instance of Book(name, author)'\n        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (name, author))\n\n    @classmethod\n    def _make(cls, iterable, new=tuple.__new__, len=len):\n        'Make a new Book object from a sequence or iterable'\n        result = new(cls, iterable)\n        if len(result) != 2:\n            raise TypeError('Expected 2 arguments, got %d' % len(result))\n        return result\n\n    def _replace(_self, **kwds):\n        'Return a new Book object replacing specified fields with new values'\n        result = _self._make(map(kwds.pop, ('name', 'author'), _self))\n        if kwds:\n            raise ValueError('Got unexpected field names: %r' % list(kwds))\n        return result\n\n    def __repr__(self):\n        'Return a nicely formatted representation string'\n        return self.__class__.__name__ + '(name=%r, author=%r)' % self\n\n    def _asdict(self):\n        'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values.'\n        return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))\n\n    def __getnewargs__(self):\n        'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'\n        return tuple(self)\n\n    name = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')\n\n    author = _property(_itemgetter(1), doc='Alias for field number 1')\n\n"
```

However, if we reference it using `exec` then subsequent calls to `_source` will raise an error.

```
In [87]: Book = namedtuple('Book', 'name, author')
In [88]: exec(Book._source)
In [89]: Book._source
AttributeError: type object 'Book' has no attribute '_source'
```

What's the mechanism behind it?

Comment: Maybe related to the fact that the `_source` subclasses `tuple` instead of `namedtuple`? (And doesn't then redefine `_source`)

Answer (score 1):

`collections.namedtuple` creates a class object by filling out the template string and passing it to `exec`. The class object only gets the `_source` attribute *after* it's created, i.e., *the template string does not define it* -- otherwise the template would be recursive. This means that if you `exec` the template yourself, you'll get the same class but without the `_source` attribute.

Then, `exec(Book._source)` runs `Book._source` in the current namespace and replaces the original `Book` class with the new class generated from that string (because the names match), which does not have the `_source` attribute. Provide your own globals dictionary and see the difference:

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple

In [2]: Book = namedtuple('Book', 'name, author')

In [3]: ns = {}; exec(Book._source, ns)

In [4]: hasattr(Book, '_source')
Out[4]: True

In [5]: hasattr(ns['Book'], '_source')
Out[5]: False
```

As a side note, that attribute was removed altogether in Python 3.7.